# Implement Siamese Network in Keras Issue

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I was trying to implement a Siamese Network with Keras, I have two input data,

X1 shape: (10000, 52)
X2 shape: (10000, 600)

Each sample in X1 is assumed similar to sample in X2. For example: X1[0] is similar to X2[0]. Thus, I used the "cosine similarity" when two inputs are merged. I was trying to use the following code:

```
def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
'''Contrastive loss from Hadsell-et-al.'06
http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/hadsell-chopra-lecun-06.pdf
'''

margin = 1
return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))

left_branch = Sequential()
left_branch.add(Embedding(1000, 32, input_length=52))
left_branch.add(LSTM(64))
left_branch.add(Dense(256))

right_branch = Sequential()
right_branch.add(Embedding(1000, 32, input_length=600))
right_branch.add(LSTM(64))
right_branch.add(Dense(256))

merged = Merge([left_branch, right_branch], mode='cos',dot_axes=1)

final_model = Sequential()
final_model.add(merged)
final_model.summary()

x1 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(10000, 52))
x2 = np.random.randint(1000, size=(10000, 600))
y = np.ones((10000,),dtype=np.int)

final_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=contrastive_loss)

final_model.fit([x1, x2], y, nb_epoch=2, batch_size=32)

getoutput_t = K.function([merged.layers[0].layers[0].input], [merged.layers[0].layers[2].output])

getoutput_d = K.function([merged.layers[1].layers[0].input], [merged.layers[1].layers[2].output])

t1 = getoutput_t([x1])[0]

t2 = getoutput_d([x2])[0]
```

My issue is: after training, t1[0] was very similar to t1[1], but very different from t2[0]. I checked the output of t1 and t2, the generated output were strange:

t1:

array([[ -3.48182112e-01, 6.57344190e-03, -6.75882818e-03,
4.11706511e-03, -2.41146213e-03, -1.14028137e-02,
2.49683809e+00, -9.19755269e-03, -2.37327255e-02....]

[ -3.48182231e-01, 6.57369522e-03, -6.75880583e-03,
4.11719829e-03, -2.41167075e-03, -1.14026833e-02,
2.49683785e+00, -9.19752941e-03, -2.37324722e-02,...]
.......]])

The t1[0] was almost same to t1[1], same issue also was found in t2.

Thus, I have to concerns:

Is there any issue in my Siamese model? (e.g. loss function or layer design)

I don't have negative sampling so far, thus, the target values are "1", is this the issue?

Answer (score 2):

### Only positive pairs is an issue

If by

> the target values are "1", is this the issue?

You mean you don't have negative/dissimilar pairs, then yes, this is an issue. Please disregard the remainder of this answer if this is not your case.

### Why is having only positive pairs an issue

On page 3 of the [paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/hadsell-chopra-lecun-06.pdf) referenced in your source code:

> The contrastive term involving dissimilar pairs, LD, is crucial.
>   Simply minimizing DW (X~ 1, X~ 2) over the set of all similar pairs
>   will usually lead to a collapsed solution, since DW and the loss L
>   could then be made zero **by setting GW to a constant**. Most energy-based
>   models require the use of an explicit contrastive term in the loss
>   function.

Where the "contrastive term" is the loss function term that depends on the negative pairs. L_D in equation 3. Please note GW is the model/mapping from input to output vectors. Basically, without negative pairs the learner can reach its optimization goal (which is reduced to minimizing the distance between similar/positive pairs) by learning a trivial model that just maps the input vectors to the same output vector.

Intuitively, the contrastive loss helps you find the optimal model by forcing it to balance minimizing the distance between similar pairs, while maximizing (up to a margin) the distance between dissimilar pairs using the same parameters set in GW.

### How to generate negative pairs if you don't have them

If you don't have negative pairs, you can try to generate negative pairs by randomly pairing elements from your dataset.

There's an example of the use of contrastive loss in the main Keras repo:

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese_graph.py

Comment: Thanks. I am going to make negative sampling. Also, could you verify if my model is correct? If my model is correct, I would only focus on making dissimilar data

Comment: I tried to use the Siamese example with negative sampling with my model, but the problem is still there. The t1[0] is similar to t1[n]. Is there any problem in my model?

Comment: Just to clarify: by "tried to use the Siamese example with negative sampling" is the example the code you provided in your post or the link I provided to the Keras repository Siamese example?

Comment: In any case, could you please post an updated version of the code with negative pairs that might have an issue in a form? Then I can try to repro it.

Comment: Yes, I used the original code from the link you provided, it was working. But I am working on how to make negative sampling data for my own data. I have to input data, that are different, any idea to make negative sampling data?

Comment: It depends on your data distribution. If negative pairs are much more likely in your universe of possible pairs, you can try to pair random elements like in the link I provided (random digit pairs). Sometimes random pairs alone cannot represent borderline pairs, for instance pairs that "look positive" but are really negative and vice-versa. If this matters for your task, you may need to find a way of collecting this borderline labeled data.

Comment: thanks, I've made the negative sampling. Have you tried to ran mnist_siamese_graph example? I found t1[0] is similar to t2[0], but t1[0] is also similar to t1[n]. Any suggestion from you?